# Sort Map in Dart/Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a Map<String, dynamic> i get from a json response as below.

```dart
map = {
  "status": "Success",
  "payments": [
    {
      "id": 99,
      "groupID": 19,
      "paymentDueDate": "2023-05-12",
      "paymentDate": null,
      "userID": 13,
      "amount": 500,
      "forDuration": "May",
      "proofOfPayment": null,
      "paymentMode": null,
      "paymentID": null,
      "paymentToken": null,
      "approvedBy": null,
      "approvedAt": null,
      "status": "pending",
      "note": "",
      "created_at": "2023-05-09T03:39:01.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2023-05-09T03:39:01.000000Z"
    }
  ]
};
```

I will like to sort by "paymentDueDate". This looks like a map of lists. Can someone help me on how i can achieve this sorting in flutter? below is what i have tried but it is not working.

```dart
 map["payments"].sort(
    (a, b) => (
      a[DateTime.tryParse('paymentDueDate')].compareTo(
        b[DateTime.tryParse('paymentDueDate')],
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this

```
List<dynamic> payments = map["payments"];
payments.sort((a, b) {
  final DateTime aDate = DateTime.parse(a["paymentDueDate"]);
  final DateTime bDate = DateTime.parse(b["paymentDueDate"]);
  return aDate.compareTo(bDate);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it in this way then:

```
map["payments"].sort((a, b) {   
final DateTime? aDueDate = DateTime.tryParse(a?["paymentDueDate"]);
final DateTime? bDueDate = DateTime.tryParse(b?["paymentDueDate"]);

  if (aDueDate == null || bDueDate == null) {
    // Handle null or invalid dates if necessary
    return 0;   }

  return aDueDate.compareTo(bDueDate); });
```

Comment: Thanks. Am getting the following error on this. The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.